# Exporting BigCommerce Reviews / Web Scraping

Tags: web-scraping, bigcommerce

So I want to migrate my BigCommerce store to an opensource platform, but I have accumulated lots of reviews over the last couple of years. BigCommerce does not have a way to export these reviews. After some research I found a technique called "Web Scraping". The page I need to extract the data from is in my administration dashboard. Is it possible to use this technique for this situation? If so, can someone help me get started? If not, any other suggestions?

Here's a screenshot of the review page in my admin dashboard: http://postimg.org/image/j2x8lm493/

Also, once if I am able to get the reviews extracted. Is is possible to created my own custom review module on the opensource platform that I can import them into with the correct dates? Thanks for your help in advnace guys! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reviews can be found in the rendered HTML under the div id ProductReviews, with the class ProductReviewList.

You'd have to parse each product page, and you can store the data however you please

EDIT: What data are you trying to export that is only included in the Admin Panel?

Reviews can also be retrieved using the Bigcommerce API. They have the Client Libraries in several forms and flavors, which are available at https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/clients

With a quick dump via the Bigcommerce API, you would be able to pull the following information for each review:

*id*    integer 
*product_id*    integer (The ID of the product the review belongs to)
*author*    string  
*date_created*  date    
*rating*    int 
*title* string  (The name of the review)
*review*    text    (The body of the review)
*status*    int

As for your question about your open source cart, building out an extension or plugin would depends on what cart you'd be using.

Comment: perfect. Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks